# How to add data to a row in a new dataframe based on information in the column of a separate dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that lists genes as column names, with no values added yet.

```
print(output_df)
     a    b     c     d     e     f
```

I have 10 dataframes that list the genes and expression data (ecample of 2 here,

```
Gene     expression         Gene     expression
a        0.3                a        0.1
b        0.1                c        -0.3
e        0.2                d        0.05
f        0.2                f        -0.1
```

For each dataset, I am trying to add a row to the main dataframe that includes the expression data for that gene, with an output ideally like the below

```
Ideal Output:

     a     b     c     d     e     f
1    0.3   0.1   NA    NA    0.2   0.2
2    0.1   NA    -0.3  0.05  NA    -0.1
```

I am very stuck, and the only way I can think about it is like this, but not sure where to start. I also know for loops are very inefficient

```
datasets <- list.files(data_dir)

for (dataset in datasets){
  df <- read.csv(dataset, sep="\t")
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df$gene[i] == ###column in output_df){
      ###add row with expression data
    }
    else {NA}
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tibble)
map_dfr(datasets, ~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
                    deframe %>%
                    as.data.frame.list)
```